# Typescript call signatures

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code from the typescript handbook [call_signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures):

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(fn.description + " returned " + fn(6));
}
```

Now I want to initialise a `DescribableFunction` object, but I'm not sure what I should pass as the second argument. What constitutes to a valid `DescribableFunction` object in this situation?

Comment: Also relevant: [Having trouble understanding call signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65113481) | [ts a type that is a function and a property at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68622766) | [Call signatures in typescript with 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68431840) | [Why does TypeScript track mutation of function static properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68643123)

Comment: Yes, and perhaps a bit more than the comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript), [functions are first-class objects which can have properties and methods like any other object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions).

According to this definition:

```
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (someArg: number): boolean;
};
```

a `DescribableFunction` is a function that takes a `number` argument and returns a `boolean`, and also has a `description` property of type `string`.

You can make one of these either by calling [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy properties into a function, like this:

```
const df = Object.assign(
  (someArg: number) => someArg > 3, 
  { description: "more than three" }
);
doSomething(df); // no error, logs "more than three returned true"
```

Or just by making a function [and assigning properties to it afterward](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#properties-declarations-on-functions):

```
function df2(someArg: number) {
    return false;
}
df2.description = "always false";
doSomething(df2); // no error, logs "always false returned false"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=51#code/C4TwDgpgBAIhDOBjATgSwEYEN0BsIDEBXAO0WFQHtioBeKAbwCgoWoATBFVMcqgLijxgaYgHMA3M1YAKeBQC2EAILJRA4oXnoIyAJQD0FCnkzFJAX0kAzEmUrU2FAMoKIwABaox0q8QFwkNCxcAlteYl0GKRZEKjk8ADocClEfYgSOQO5wqABqKAAiKGQ3QmRiCDZCvKhfaQA2XV0LRkZY4iF2K1ooAHl0ACsIMgTMeHhUUWJpWVcVNSgNLR1ImgA+QTnVKA2AZgAaBnZONB57AQL5ChKoD1Nb9xKIIvNmxkcXRQ8vVLYrZqgAHpAYUrjc7tQPE9iqVypVbshCM9WjZSDk-gAmWaKebqTTaPRRVgw4BlahWTA4eAQFqYjInbL2HoFSkAd0wIHgtUp1IKkg+rm+3kxAOBhTZHK5FKp0BKpLhVWlvKAA)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just to be sure, the DescribableFunction object is actually a function type, right? I tried to log the type of both df and df2 and got 'function', which to my understanding is that we need to initialise the object as a function, rather than a normal object like {someKey: someValue}. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know you either cannot or should not try to make a normal object callable.  The best way to approach it is to start with a function and add properties and not try to do the reverse.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335983/can-you-make-an-object-callable for discussion.